# How to create JSON payload using power shell Foreach loop

Tags: json, powershell, email, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

**Requirement:** To send E-Mail via send grid account (Send Grid API)  by attaching multiple attachments.

**Description:** I am able to create json payload and able to send with single attachment by hard coding attachment values. I am opening window forms dialog and able to select single/multiple files that needs to be attached.

**Code:**

```
          $FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{ 
    InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop') 
    #Filter = 'Documents (*.docx)|*.docx|SpreadSheet (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx'
    Filter           = 'All files (*.*)| *.*'
    Title            = 'Select  File(s) for Attachments'
    Multiselect      = $true
  }
  $FileBrowser.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
  $FilesEncodedContents = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
  $AttachmentsjsonRequest = @()
  if ($FileBrowser.FileNames.Count -gt 0) {
    foreach ($file in $FileBrowser.FileNames) {
      [string] $filerawContent = $null
      $filedetails = Get-Item $file
      $filerawContent = ConvertToBase64Encode $file

      if (![string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($filerawContent)) {
        $FilesEncodedContents.Add($filerawContent) 
          $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name filename -Value (Get-Item $file).Name
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name content_id -Value (Get-Item $file).Name
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name content -Value $filerawContent
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name disposition -Value 'attachment'
        $AttachmentsjsonRequest += $obj
      }
    }
  }    
      Write-Host "$AttachmentsjsonRequest"

          $headers = @{ }
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $ApiKey")
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$jsonRequest = [ordered]@{
  personalizations = @(@{to = @(@{email = "$MailTo" })
      subject               = "$Subject" 
    })
  from             = @{email = "no-reply@xxx.com" }
  attachments      = "$AttachmentsjsonRequest"
  content          = @( @{ type = "text/plain"
      value            = "Sample Mail Body" 
    }
  )
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
           Write-Host $jsonRequest | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
       Invoke-RestMethod   -Uri "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send" -Method Post -Headers 
    $headers -Body $jsonRequest

Write-Host "Mail Sent"



      #region ConvertToBase64Encode
     Function ConvertToBase64Encode([string] $AttachementFile) {
     [string] $fileContentEncoded = $null
     if (Test-Path $AttachementFile -PathType leaf) {
$fileContent = get-content $AttachementFile
$fileContentBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($fileContent)
$fileContentEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentBytes)
$fileContentEncoded | set-content ((Get-Item -Path $AttachementFile).Name + ".b64")
   }
   else {
     $fileContentEncoded = $null
     Write-Host "File : $FileAttachment not exists,skipping and continue to add if any other 
   attachments  uploaded"
    }
    return $fileContentEncoded

     }
      #endregion
```

**Problem:** [UPDATED]

Am getting below error after trying to upload single or multiple attachments

```
  {"errors":[{"message":"Invalid type. Expected: array, given: string.","field":"attachments","help":"http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.attachments"}]} .
```

Reference Links : 
Send Grid API Documentation:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html

Comment: tried with Array Object. Updated code and still getting error. What is still wrong?

Comment: You are not passing the $jsonRequest variable to the -Body parameter of Invoke-RestMethod: `Invoke-RestMethod   -Uri "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send" -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $jsonRequest`

Comment: @Zachafer, Sorry it seems it was missed while updating the code before it was present.Still if we try with updated code we get error after invoking API unless if we modify code as per solution I had answered.

Comment: how to add multiple email addresses in the `to` section?

Comment: @Pradeep Create an array and add emails and assign .
personalizations = @(@{to = @($validMails)

$validMails is array type

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS, can you please provide the sample script

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to consider not building the JSON as a text, first build a Powshell object that you convert to JSON with `ConvertTo-Json`.

Using this method, arrays will be correctly represented in JSON. don't forget to set the `-DEPTH` param.

```
attachments array[object] An array of objects in which you can specify any attachments you want to include.
```

So in your Powershell object `attachments` is going to be a `@()`.

of objects with content, type, filename, disposition, conten_id properties.

Comment: I tried with object also as i am very new to powershell i am unable to make it. could you please help with some of code or reference links.

Answer (score 0):

I realized error details in depth in late . It was giving hint in JSON payload "attachments" field is showing as string rather than array object which it is fixed by adding ***@(@()) to attachmentjsonrequest***  in **"$jsonrequest"** variable .

**In Short:** "**attachmentjsonrequest** is an array object which needs to convert to JSON payload by using ***@()***

Thanks for suggesting to use array object.

```
       attachments      = @(@($AttachmentsjsonRequest))
```